# Warning: parsing failure using read_csv in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have a big csv file (405,734 KB). When I try to read it using `read_csv` I get:

```
EGRESOS_2016 <- read_csv("Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(...
)
See spec(...) for full column specifications.
|===========================================================================================================| 100%  396 MB
Warning: 2081365 parsing failures.
 row           col           expected      actual                            file
1315 SA_LABOR      1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 99          'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
1315 SA_EXPUL      1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 99          'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
1324 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000054 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
1903 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000042 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
2082 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000655 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
.... ............. .................. ........... ...............................
See problems(...) for more details.
```

When I use `problems()` and `spec()` I get:

```
spec()
cols(
  ID = col_double(),
  CLUES = col_character(),
  FOLIO = col_double(),
  EGRESO = col_character(),
  INGRE = col_character(),
  DIAS_ESTA = col_double(),
  TUHPSIQ = col_logical(),
  SERVHC = col_logical(),
  SERVHP = col_logical(),
  CVEEDAD = col_double(),
  EDAD = col_double(),
  NACIOEN = col_double(),
  SEXO = col_double(),
  PESO = col_double(),
  TALLA = col_double(),
  DERHAB = col_double(),
  ENTIDAD = col_double(),
  MUNIC = col_double(),
  LOC = col_double(),
  INDIGENA = col_double(),
  HABLA_LENGUA = col_double(),
  LENGUA_INDIGENA = col_double(),
  HABLA_ESP = col_double(),
  TIPSERV = col_double(),
  SERVICIOINGRE = col_double(),
  SERVICIO02 = col_logical(),
  SERVICIO03 = col_logical(),
  SERVICIOEGRE = col_double(),
  SA_LABOR = col_logical(),
  SA_EXPUL = col_logical(),
  SA_RECUP = col_double(),
  SA_INTEN = col_logical(),
  SA_INTERM = col_logical(),
  PROCED = col_double(),
  CLUESPROCED = col_character(),
  MOTEGRE = col_double(),
  CLUESREFERIDO = col_logical(),
  DIAG_INI = col_character(),
  AFECPRIN = col_character(),
  VEZ = col_double(),
  INFEC = col_double(),
  CAUSAEXT = col_character(),
  TRAUMAT = col_double(),
  LUGAR = col_double(),
  MES_ESTADISTICO = col_double()
)

problems()
A tibble: 2,081,365 x 5
     row col           expected           actual      file                           
   <int> <chr>         <chr>              <chr>       <chr>                          
 1  1315 SA_LABOR      1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 99          'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 2  1315 SA_EXPUL      1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE 99          'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 3  1324 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000054 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 4  1903 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000042 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 5  2082 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000655 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 6  2160 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000054 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 7  2331 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000614 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 8  3118 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000042 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 9  3164 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000655 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
10  3286 CLUESREFERIDO 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE ASSSA000404 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
# ... with 2,081,355 more rows
```

If I use `readr` there are `2953109` observations in my dataframe. If I use `base` I get `2955144` observations. Is there a way to read my csv correctly and be sure I'm getting all the observations from it?

Comment: It meant to use `spec(EGRESOS_2016)`

Comment: You may rerun with `col_types` as `character` to read all as character i.e. `EGRESOS_2016 <- read_csv("Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv", col_types = cols(.default = "c"))` and later convert the column types `EGRESOS_2016 <- type.convert(EGRESOS_2016, as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: There are still 1,123,354 parsing  failures, I think it is because of all the `NA`.

`row col   expected   actual     file                           
    <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>                          
 1 115440 NA    45 columns 46 columns 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 2 115441 NA    45 columns 46 columns 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 3 115442 NA    45 columns 46 columns 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'
 4 115443 NA    45 columns 46 columns 'Egresos SAEH/EGRESOS_2016.csv'`